# Node.js PubSub new v1.SubscriberClient() pull request pulls very few messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I need to pull 2500 messages so I have set maxMessages to 2500, but still it pulls only 500 messages maximum and often it pulls less then 10 messages also. Given that I concurrently pull messages in some delay of 2 - 2.5 secs.

Kindly help me understand the issue and help me fix this

Answer (score 0):

Unary pull can only pull up to 1000 messages at a time. However, it it is not atypical for it to pull fewer at a time. The system trades off returning fuller responses with returning responses more quickly in order to reduce latency. If you want to receive messages as quickly as possible, you should be using [streaming pull via the high-level client library](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#client_library_code_samples). If you absolutely must use unary pull, then you need to have dozens of requests outstanding simultaneously at all times in order to maximize the flow of messages.

Comment: ack, can you kindly clarify what do you meant by outstanding requests, is there any way to raise a request and fetch the messages asynchronously or you meant parallel calls to new v1.SubscriberClient().pull, Thanks

Comment: You would make parallel calls to v1.SubscriberClient().pull. "Outstanding requests" means "requests that have been sent to the server, but have not yet had a response returned."

Comment: Understood, thanks for the clarification, so I implemented a code to parallel call  v1.SubscriberClient().pull 7 times however there is no, such increase in the speed of consumption also multiple times it returned 0 messages altogether.
note: I am calling this every 2 seconds, and I fired 15k messages to the topic and it took almost 45-55 minutes to consume all of them.

just fyi, my end goal here is to bulk consume messages also in a very short period (as much as possible).

Comment: Calling pull 7 times every 2 seconds is not going to be sufficient. As the answer stated: you need to have dozens of requests outstanding simultaneously at all times. You should be in a constant state of having many requests outstanding. As soon as a request gets a response, you need to fire a new request immediately. If you want to consume most quickly, though, you need to switch to streaming pull.

Comment: Also can review once this: https://codeshare.io/wnkkp9, thanks

Comment: Also @Kamal Aboul-Hosn, I am observing a pattern, like even If I increase the number of pulls per second and reduce the time gap we don`t end up increasing the speed of consumption with v1.SubscriberClient().pull, it decreases over time and increases also, seems like a rate-limiting condition, given that I am less than the mentioned size https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/quotas, Am I missing something else? Thanks for you help here.